# Nuxt3 modules are not included in build

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have [nuxt3js](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/) project (version: v3.0.0-rc.3). For additional server-side features like WebSocket server; Authentication Checks; Database connection; ..., I have created a modules folder with all this additional logic.

```
project
┣ modules
┃ ┣ auth
┃ ┃ ┣ index.ts
┃ ┃ ┗ ...
┃ ┗ websocket
┃ ┃ ┗ index.ts
┃ ┗ ...
┃   ┗ ...
┣ ...
┣ nuxt.config.ts
┃ 
┗ ...
```

Then in *nuxt.config.ts* I have added them like so:

```
// nuxt.config.ts
import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt";

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ...
  modules: [
    ...
    "~/modules/auth/index.ts",
    "~/modules/websocket/index.ts",
    ...
  ],
  ...
});
```

Project logic works fine while developing, and starting everything with `yarn dev`, before everything starts all modules are executed one by one as excpected. Now when the time has come to the point when the project is ready for its first deployment I am running `yarn build` which finishes with no errors and produces following folder:

```
.output
 ┣ public
 ┃ ┗ _nuxt
 ┃ ┃ ┗ ...
 ┣ server
 ┃ ┣ chunks
 ┃ ┃ ┗ ...
 ┃ ┣ node_modules
 ┃ ┃ ┗ ...
 ┃ ┃   ┗ ...
 ┃ ┣ index.mjs
 ┃ ┣ index.mjs.map
 ┃ ┗ package.json
 ┗ nitro.json
```

Now starting the server with hinted command `node .output/server/index.mjs` successfully starts a server that is accessible from the browser, the only problem is that none of my *modules* logic is working, it seems as `yarn build` does not include my *modules* to the end build.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe please check if any code / package needs to be added in the nuxt.config.js transpile section. e.g headless ui & @aspida/axios needs to be added

```
build: {
    transpile: ['@headlessui/vue', '@aspida/axios'],
}
```

Read more: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/going-further/esm/#transpiling-libraries